Partykit predict function throws warning when predicting with new data
Im trying to predict new data with a ctree object. I get this warning message when I run the function:
b1b2_party <- ctree(factor(final_category_bin) ~ ., data = train, control = ctree_control(maxsurrogate = 3))
predict.party(b1b2_party, newdata = test, type = "response")
Warning message:
In retid[indx] <- fitted_node(kids_node(node)[[i]], data, vmatch,  :
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
The result of predict.party is a vector of all 1s (my target variable is a factor with levels 0 and 1), which leads me to believe that this warning is really messing with the results.
The test data was handled the same way as the training data. I haven't found a way to create a reproducible example for this issue, and I apologize for that. But I am wondering if anyone else has encountered this warning and what their way forward was.
I tried to predict new data with a ctree object. I expected a mix of conclusions but got all 1s returned and a warning.

Hello, welcome to SO. Can you post some of your data? This will make it much easier to reproduce the issue and see what's going on. You could copy-paste the output of dput(head(train, 20)) into your question. Also, please use markdown to format your posts.

+1 Please try to prepare a minimal reproducible example. My guess is that this is somehow related to the handling of NAs - but I couldn't replicate the problem, yet.
